# function from R.h is not found when compiling C code into so

Tags: r, c, compilation

I am trying to convert R code into Python with some changes. The problem is that some of the underlying code for R is written in C and has .C('function') type of function.

I can't code in C, so I decide to compile an .so file, so I could use the function from there in my Python code. However, I am encountering a problem when compiling the .so file. It seems that couple of functions that are supposed to be included in R.h are not found by C when I am compiling. So I get the following error.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_Rf_revsort", referenced from:
      _sort_univ_surv_index_double in survivalBIV_test-466caf.o
  "_rsort_with_index", referenced from:
      _KaplanMeierValueSort in survivalBIV_test-466caf.o
      _KaplanMeierVectorSort in survivalBIV_test-466caf.o
      _WeightsNNE in survivalBIV_test-466caf.o
      _BivDistIPCW in survivalBIV_test-466caf.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Now, I have tried to locate this files in the `R/include` folder and found the file `R_ext/Utils.h` which contains the following code

```
/* Included by R.h: API */

#ifndef R_EXT_UTILS_H_
#define R_EXT_UTILS_H_

#include <R_ext/Boolean.h>
#include <R_ext/Complex.h>

#if defined(__cplusplus) && !defined(DO_NOT_USE_CXX_HEADERS)
# include <cstddef>
# define R_SIZE_T std::size_t
#else
# include <stddef.h>
# define R_SIZE_T size_t
#endif

#define revsort       Rf_revsort
#define iPsort        Rf_iPsort
#define rPsort        Rf_rPsort
#define cPsort        Rf_cPsort
#define IndexWidth    Rf_IndexWidth
#define setIVector    Rf_setIVector
#define setRVector    Rf_setRVector
#define StringFalse   Rf_StringFalse
#define StringTrue    Rf_StringTrue
#define isBlankString Rf_isBlankString

#ifdef  __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

/* ../../main/sort.c : */
void    R_isort(int*, int);
void    R_rsort(double*, int);
void    R_csort(Rcomplex*, int);
void    rsort_with_index(double *, int *, int);
void    revsort(double*, int*, int);/* reverse; sort i[] alongside */
void    iPsort(int*,    int, int);
void    rPsort(double*, int, int);
void    cPsort(Rcomplex*, int, int);
```

So, I can see that these functions are defined here but not explicitly as I can't see what they actually do. They are probably exported from somewhere else.

I am lost as to why these functions are not found during C compilation and can't understand how to find these functions manually to understand exactly what they do. Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: It is the Linker that has a problem. You probably need to specify an extra library to link with your code. (I don't know which one though)

Comment: Can you point me to the resources that describe this problem? I.e. how to set the linker correctly, so maybe I can figure out the rest?

Comment: If you find some ".so" files in the R installation tree, you can try to use them by adding "-L /path/to/R/libs -l yourRlib". The yourRlib will be called libyourRlib.so on a Linux system. You'll have to add the flags for the linker to your gcc command line that produces your error.

Comment: Post your build commands (and their output) as well. And your code. You are on *OSX*? [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: How are you compiling your code? As Roland said, the issue is the linker, but you shouldn’t be compiling your code manually anyway — use `R CMD SHLIB`, which takes care of all of that.

Comment: Hi Konrad! Yes, you are absolutely right. I have tried it earlier and it worked. The problem was for me that I was creating .dylib file instead of .so, because I didn't specify it. If you want, you can post this as an answer and I will mark it.